# .map() working outside of render function, but fails when used inside render

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, object, redux

I'm not a very experienced developer, so I may be missing something simple. I have an array of objects that I am getting from my redux state (this.props.assignments.assignments). I am getting a .map() is not a function when trying to call displayAssignments() in my render return. However, I have another function that is attached to an onClick that is doing the same map and logging "name" into the console, and that one works as expected (when i comment out displayAssignments()). I have no idea why the .map() would work on my onClick but not on displayAssignments.

I included the showAssignments function simply to test if my data could even be mapped...which confused me even more because that one works...

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { getAssignments } from '../../Actions/assignmentActions.js';

class Assignments extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.getAssignments();
  };

  showAssignments = () => {
    console.log(this.props.assignments.assignments);
    this.props.assignments.assignments.map(assignment => (
      console.log(assignment.name)
    ));
  };
  displayAssignments = () => {
    this.props.assignments.assignments.map(assignment => {
      return (
        <div>
          <p>{assignment.name}</p>
          <p>{assignment.description}</p>
        </div>
      )
    })
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>Assignments</h1>
        <button onClick={this.showAssignments}>Click Me</button>
        {this.displayAssignments()}
      </div>
    );
  };
};

Assignments.propTypes = {
  getAssignments: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  assignments: PropTypes.object.isRequired
};

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  assignments: state.assignments
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps, { getAssignments })(Assignments);
```

Expected: to render name and description of assignments by way of mapping
Actual: getting this.props.assignments.assignments.map is not a function

Comment: Isn't `this.props.getAssignments()` asynchronous?

Answer (score 1):

You should return your `map()` as a value of `displayAssigments`:

```
displayAssignments = () => {
    return this.props.assignments.assignments.map(assignment => {
      return (
        <div>
          <p>{assignment.name}</p>
          <p>{assignment.description}</p>
        </div>
      )
    })
  };
```

Or just remove the curly bracket which wrap `.map()`:

```
displayAssignments = () => this.props.assignments.assignments.map(assignment => 
  <div>
    <p>{assignment.name}</p>
    <p>{assignment.description}</p>
  </div>
)
```

For your error is not function, make sure that `this.props.assignments.assignments` is an `Array`.

Comment: Those are things you should/could do, but that doesn't explain the null pointer, does it? It should just be displaying nothing. What do you think?

Comment: Still not an answer to the actual question... Why is it null in one place and not the other? You are just remedying the problem without understanding the root cause.

Comment: Thanks guys! My initial assignments state was set to {} instead of [ ]....completely missed that.....works perfectly now!

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that, given the fact that you call `getAssignments()` in the `componentDidMount` method, it means there is a section of time between when the component is mounted and the assignment field is populated in the store in which there are no assignments, hence why you get the `.map() is not a function` error.

The click handler is only called after the asynchronous operation finishes so `assignments` is defined by then.

To fix this, you can change your default state for the assignments field to be:

```
{
   "assignments":[]
}
```

Another problem with your code, as @radonirina-maminiaina has mentioned, is that your `displayAssignments` function does not return the result of the maps so the HTML will be blank

The `Array.map` function creates a new array from the given array with the function provided applied to each element.

Another thing to consider is why you need `assignments.assignments` to get to the list of assignments. You could probably change your actions or reducer to remove the nesting.

Comment: !! Thanks Alex, I had my default assignments state set to an object {}. I literally looked everywhere but did not think to check that!! Works perfectly now